# Splitting and aggregating count from arrays

Tags: mongodb

I have documents in my MongoDB instance that look like the following

```
{
  ...
  regions: ["Region-West", "Region-HC"],
  care_levels: ["Memory Care"],
  ...
}
{
  ...
  regions: ["Region-West", "Region-SC"],
  care_levels: ["Physical Rehab"],
  ...
}
{
  ...
  regions: ["Region-East", "Region-NC"],
  care_levels: ["Physical Rehab"],
  ...
}
```

The regions and care levels are both an array of strings. I want to perform a count of documents mapped by a specific set of regions and care_levels. For example -

```
Region-East, Physical Rehab => 20
Region-East, Memory Care => 20
Region-West, Memory Care => 30
```

I am running the following query

```
db.incidents.aggregate([
    {$match:
    {"care_levels": { $size: 1, $in: ["Memory Care", "Physical Rehab"] }},
    },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "regions": "$regions",
            "care_levels": "$care_levels",
        },
        "incidentCount": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},
])
```

and I get the result as

```
{ "_id" : { "regions" : [ "Region-East", "Region-HC" ], "care_levels" : [ "Memory Care" ] }, "incidentCount" : 2409 }
{ "_id" : { "regions" : [ "Region-East", "Region-HC" ], "care_levels" : [ "Physical Rehab" ] }, "incidentCount" : 2459 }
{ "_id" : { "regions" : [ "Region-East", "Region-SC" ], "care_levels" : [ "Memory Care" ] }, "incidentCount" : 2504 }
{ "_id" : { "regions" : [ "Region-West", "Region-HC" ], "care_levels" : [ "Memory Care" ] }, "incidentCount" : 2382 }
{ "_id" : { "regions" : [ "Region-West", "Region-HC" ], "care_levels" : [ "Physical Rehab" ] }, "incidentCount" : 2475 }
{ "_id" : { "regions" : [ "Region-East", "Region-SC" ], "care_levels" : [ "Physical Rehab" ] }, "incidentCount" : 2478 }
{ "_id" : { "regions" : [ "Region-South", "Region-HC" ], "care_levels" : [ "Physical Rehab" ] }, "incidentCount" : 2405 }
{ "_id" : { "regions" : [ "Region-West", "Region-SC" ], "care_levels" : [ "Memory Care" ] }, "incidentCount" : 2490 }
{ "_id" : { "regions" : [ "Region-West", "Region-SC" ], "care_levels" : [ "Physical Rehab" ] }, "incidentCount" : 2433 }
{ "_id" : { "regions" : [ "Region-South", "Region-HC" ], "care_levels" : [ "Memory Care" ] }, "incidentCount" : 2465 }
```

I want to filter out the regions that I don't care about. In this case, I don't want the split for Region-SC and Region-HC and the count of Region-West/East/South should be the sum of the values from the Region-SC and Region-HC split.

Specifically in this case, I want the values

```
Region-East, Memory Care => (2409 + 2504)
Region-West, Memory Care => (2382 + 2490)
```

How do I achieve this through further aggregation ?

Answer (score 0):

I realized a simple $unwind at the beginning does what I need. I was using a wrong syntax for it hence the problems before.